# Hide toolbar item on Menu open

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, toolbar

I trying to build a menu like the Notes app on iOS. On press of the ellipsis-circle button, it should release focus on the text and hide the Done toolbar item.

This is my code:

```
@FocusState private var isEditing: Bool

var body: some View {
AnnotatedTextEditor(text: $text)
    .focused($isEditing)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Menu {
                Button(role: .destructive, action: delete) {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: .trash)
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Menu", systemImage: .ellipsisCircle)
            }
            .onPress {
                isEditing = false
            }
            
            if (isEditing) {
                Button("Done", action: done)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The AnnotatedTextEditor is a UITextView wrapped in a UITextViewRepresentable for SwiftUI compatibility.

Working: The text view is unfocused and the done toolbar item disappears when the menu toolbar item is presses.
Not working: the menu does not open.

When I show the Done button un-conditionally, it works as expected, so I assume the issue is that the toolbar changes on the state change.

Is there any workaround to achieve hiding the toolbar's done button on menu open?

Screenshots:

My app (not working as expected):

[image: my app, pre tap]
[image: my app, post tap]

iOS Notes app (working as expected):

[image: iOS Notes, pre tap]
[image: iOS Notes, post tap]

Comment: It might make more sense to attach the `Done` item's visibility to whether your text view has the focus. Selecting the menu will cause the text view to lose focus, which then hides the button – and means you don't have to interfere with the menu's tap handling.

Comment: Selecting the menu does not automatically cause the text editor to loose focus. isEditing is a @FocusState that's attached to the TextEditor. The TextEditor itself is a  UIKit UITextView in a UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your example code! I wonder if moving the items out of a `ToolbarItemGroup` might help? I'd be inclined to wrap the ellipsis menu in a `ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction)` and the done button in a `ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction)`, which should preserve the ordering of the buttons, but in a semantic way. If they're seen as separate items by the SwiftUI renderer you might have more luck?

Comment: Good point! I had tried confirmationAction and navigationBarTrailing before, which did not work. Using .primaryAction and .confirmationAction does work in preview but not on device (might be a feedback/issue for Apple then).